# Using BeautifulSoup to get the text after a strong tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape from a basketball reference page to pull out referees assigned to certain games and export that later on. To test out one game I tried the below code (and some other variations) but received an error.

```py
data = requests. Get(f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/wnba/boxscores/201506050CON.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
refs = soup.find(string = "Officials: ").next_sibling
print(refs)
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[30], line 3
      1 #data = requests.get(f"https://www.basketball-reference.com/wnba/boxscores/201506050CON.html")
      2 soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text)
----> 3 refs = soup.find(string = "Officials: ").next_sibling

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a look at the HTML on the page you referenced, and your piece looks like this:

```
<div><strong>Officials:&nbsp;</strong>Daryl Humphrey, Don Hudson, Michael Price</div>
```

The `&nbsp;` in there is a non-breaking space, so your *find* expression needs to be:

```
soup.find(string = "Officials:\xa0")
```

However, that's going to find the text, whereas what you want is the parent of the text, i.e. the `<strong>` tag, and to get the *next_sibling* of that parent tag, for example:

```
soup.find(string = "Officials:\xa0").parent.next_sibling
```

Comment: This worked just as you had it! Thank you very much.